# Flask Server Side Session Management of Files

Tags: python, flask

I am preparing to deploy my first Flask application. It now runs locally but need to prepare for a multiple, simultaneous user scenario. A complete portion of code (this is a blueprint) is below showing the method I'm trying to make work.

What happens here is a user reads in a data file and that file is stored provisionally in a temp directory. What I **want** to do is when this is deployed, create a temp directory that is unique to each new browser session. Then, the same process would occur (upload file, save that file in temp,etc).

If this happened, I don't think users would collide. So, below I'm attempting to use a session variable, but is this the right way to do this? Any suggestions on a canonical approach that would be better?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, Blueprint
from flask_session import Session
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import binom, norm  
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy import optimize 
import pandas as pd 
import os 
import tempfile
import Datatools.code as dt 
from Datatools.forms import dtFormRadio
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

data_tools = Blueprint("data_tools", __name__)

@data_tools.route('/dataTools', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def data_tools_upload():
    session["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = tempfile.gettempdir() ### Just a test
    table = '<table></table>' 
    result = '<table></table>' 
    message = ''
    var2use = None 
    vars = ''
    dt_name = ''
    dtRadios = dtFormRadio(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        tmp_filename = session["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] +'\\input.csv' ### Just a test
        if request.files:
            to_upload = request.files.get('file')
            dt_name = str(to_upload).split()[1]
            if to_upload:
                f = request.files['file']
                f.save(tmp_filename)
        if os.path.exists(tmp_filename):
            orig_df = pd.read_csv(tmp_filename)
            vars = list(orig_df.columns)
            dtRadios.varlist.choices = vars 
            var2use = dtRadios.varlist.data 
            if var2use != None:
                indx = vars.index(var2use)
                if dtRadios.dtRadioList.data == 'descriptives':
                    result = dt.get_descriptives(orig_df[vars[indx]])
                if dtRadios.dtRadioList.data == 'percentiles':
                    result = dt.get_percentiles(orig_df[vars[indx]])
                if dtRadios.dtRadioList.data == 'frequency':
                    if dtRadios.binSize.data != None:
                        bins = dtRadios.binSize.data
                    result = dt.get_frequency(orig_df[vars[indx]], bins = bins)
                result = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result, orient='index', columns = [var2use]).to_html(classes='table table-striped table-hover', header = "true", justify = "center")
            dims = orig_df.shape
            message = 'Data file %s with %s rows and %s columns loaded.' % (dt_name, dims[0],dims[1])
            table = orig_df.head(10).to_html(classes='data', header = "true")
    return render_template('dataTools.html', results = [result], message = message, vars = vars, var_name = var2use, dtForm=dtRadios)
```